# Angular 2 could not load child routes via url

Tags: angular, url, angular-router

I have defined child routes, except that I cannot navigate to these manually from the url bar. When I type the full url it goes back to the first child route; have I missed something?

```
   {
  path: 'config',
  component: ConfigComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'wordlists', component: WordListComponent },
    { path: 'groups',  component: GroupBuilderComponent },
    { path: 'tagbuilder', component: TagBuilderComponent }
  ],
  canActivate: [RouteGuard],
  data: { allowed: ['inv'] }
   }
```

When I type in in the url http://localhost:63020/portal/config/tagbuilder, it always takes me to  http://localhost:63020/portal/config/wordlists.

How can I access each child route via url?

here is the console log of when trying to navigate to tagbuilder, but jumps back
[image]

Comment: Do you have each of these defined as Routes in your project?

Comment: yea they are all defined, but cants seems to access when I type in URL

Comment: Maybe it is your guard having side effects? ANd do you have anything in the console? You can enable tracing in your router to debug: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) `

Comment: added results from enabletracing in the question..

Comment: not sure if it'll work, but just something to try: add a default route as your *first* child. e.g. `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'wordlists', pathMatch: 'prefix' },`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I had method in the ngOnInit which caused the page to load on Wordlists page always on initialization. So when I entered in url it first fired that function inside ngOnInit, restricting to go other url, once I removed that function, I was able to access each route separately